# Pegar primeiro e último nome e abreviar nomes do meio apenas com a inicial

Tags: c#, .net, string

Gostaria de tratar a seguinte *string*:

```
string nome = "Rafael Rodrigues Arruda de Oliveira"
```

Com os critérios a seguir:

- Manter o primeiro e ultimo nome;
- Abreviar os demais nomes (nomes do meio) com a inicial do mesmo;
- Colocar um ponto (".") após a abreviação;
- Impedir abreviatura caso haja: "de","da","do","das","dos";
- Somente a inicial do nome deve ser maiúscula;

*Output* esperado: `Rafael R. A. Oliveira`

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90776/discussion-on-question-by-leohenrique-string-pegar-primeiro-e-ultimo-nome-e-ab) e pode prosseguir por lá pelo link fornecido.

Comment: Perfeita pergunta, estava procurando por algo assim, Obrigado!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assim fica bem melhor:

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(Abreviatte("Rafael Rodrigues Arruda de Oliveira"));
        WriteLine(Abreviatte("Rafael Rodrigues Arruda De Oliveira"));
    }
    public static string Abreviatte(string nome) {
        var meio = " ";
        var nomes = nome.Split(' ');
        for (var i = 1; i < nomes.Length - 1; i++) {
            if (!nomes[i].Equals("de", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                !nomes[i].Equals("da", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                !nomes[i].Equals("do", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                !nomes[i].Equals("das", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                !nomes[i].Equals("dos", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    meio += nomes[i][0] + ". ";
        }
        return nomes[0] + meio + nomes[nomes.Length - 1];
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UH1JKY). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/158NG6). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Abbreviate.cs).

Eliminei variáveis e alocações desnecessárias. Só faça operações que você precisa no seu código, se quer comparar desconsiderando a caixa das letras então compare assim, não crie uma *string* a toa para depois compará-la com outra coisa.

Note que eu normalmente usaria [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas estou considerando que quase nunca passará de 4 nomes do meio, aí a concatenação é aceitável. E também estou considerando que não precisa do máximo da otimização, caso contrário o correto seria usar [`Span`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

No código do AP e a outra resposta com LINQ, a comparação em cada nome do meio existente são 8 alocações contra uma do meu código, mas é possível eliminar até esta alocação com as técnicas citadas.

Alocar mais não torna as respostas erradas, só estou dando uma opção mais eficiente. Mas alocação é algo que prejudica bastante a execução, e o que pode não fazer diferença uma hora é usado em um laço grande e causa um enorme problema. Não a toa que boa parte das melhorias do C# e .NET tem se voltado a diminuir alocações.

Na verdade para o máximo de performance não deveria usar `Split()` também e operar caractere por caractere, mas em geral isto não é um requisito por isso também não o fiz.

Comment: Se as pessoas que viram erro na minha reposta podem informar pra eu arrumar.

Answer (score 10):

Mais um exemplo usando e abusando de Linq...

```
string nome = "Rafael Rodrigues Arruda de Oliveira";

var preposicoes = new string[] { "de", "da", "do", "das", "dos" };

var nomes = nome.ToLower().Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && !preposicoes.Contains(x));

string result = $"{nomes.First()} {string.Concat(nomes.Skip(1).Take(nomes.Count() - 2).Select(x => x.First() + ". "))}{nomes.Last()}";

result = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(result);
```

Comment: É legal, só tem um detalhe, o código não faz o que o AP quer. Eu te entendo, afinal a pergunta não dá os critérios para fazer, e este é um dos motivos dela estar fechada, mas a resposta do AP dá os critérios e precisa desconsiderar maiúsculo e minúsculo. Se melhorar isto acho que fica bom (ainda ineficiente igual a resposta do AP, mas pelo menos faz o que o AP quer).

Comment: @Maniero Uma opção seria passar a _string_ _nome_ para `ToLower()` e depois a _string_ _result_ para [TextInfo.ToTitleCase()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netframework-4.7.2), evitando deste modo outputs com **RA**fael ou **r**afael. Deixando a ineficiência de parte, aconselharia o uso do método `ToTitleCase()`? Que segundo a documentação poderá ter mudanças no futuro.

Comment: acredito que não resolve este caso não. O `ToLower()` resolve, apesar de ineficiente.

Comment: @Maniero parece que você não me entendeu, o uso de `ToTitleCase()` seria apenas no final do código para passar todas as iniciais para maiúsculas,o que eu estava perguntando era se aconselharia o seu uso visto que poderá ter mudanças no futuro.

Comment: Mas a questão não é essa, isso que você está dizendo até seria um bônus, mas não resolve o problema da comparação das *stop words*. Esse que você está falando agora não faz parte da necessidade original (pelo menos nada na pergunta ou resposta que serviu de referência indica isto), só valeria como bônus, embora eu faria diferente disto por causa da eficiência.

Comment: @Maniero editei o código como escrevi no meu primeiro comentário, que resolve o problema das _stop_ _words_ (que você não entendeu, ou me expressei mal), o que queria era uma opinião sobre o uso do `ToTitleCase()`...

Comment: Sim, o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

```
string nome = "Rafael Rodrigues Arruda de Oliveira";
string primeiro = "";
string meio = " "; // Sim, tem um espaço aqui!
string ultimo = "";

string[] nomes = nome.Split(' '); // Separa cada nome pelo espaço.

primeiro = nomes[0]; // Reserva o primeiro nome.

for (int i = 1; i < nomes.Length - 1; i++) 
{
    if (!nomes[i].ToLower().Equals("de") && !nomes[i].ToLower().Equals("da") && !nomes[i].ToLower().Equals("do") && !nomes[i].ToLower().Equals("das") && !nomes[i].ToLower().Equals("dos"))
    {
         meio += nomes[i].Substring(0, 1); // Reserva a inicial do próximo nome.
         meio += ". "; // Põe um ponto e um espaço após a inicial.
    }
}

ultimo = nomes[nomes.Length-1]; // Reserva o ultimo nome.

nome = primeiro + meio + ultimo; // Junta todos os nomes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, em java eu cheguei na seguinte solução:

```
  public static String getNumDescricaoItem(String descricaoItem) {
    if (descricaoItem.length() > 34) {
      val preposicoes = List.of("DE", "DA", "DO", "DAS", "DOS");
      val nomes = descricaoItem.toUpperCase().split(" ");
      return nomes[0]
          + " "
          + Arrays.stream(nomes)
              .limit(nomes.length - 1)
              .skip(1)
              .filter(nome -> !preposicoes.contains(nome))
              .map(nome -> nome.substring(0, 1) + ". ")
              .collect(Collectors.joining())
          + nomes[nomes.length - 1];
    }

    return descricaoItem;
  }
```

Nesse caso, o nome da pessoa que seria:
Nome Aleatorio da Silva -> NOME A. SILVA